# How to get result from failing webclient.downloadstring?

Tags: vb.net

If we use webclient.downloadstring on a server with error, we got nothing

```
        Try
            result = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.bodis.com/domainclassification?domain=" + CurrentBlog.Domain)
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        End Try
```

Usually result contains the response. But in case of error result is empty.

I want to know something. For example, even if the result is bad, usually there is a custom 404 message, etc.

The api.bodis.com is problematic because it mix secure and non secure stuff. However, it gives output anyway in internet explorer. I want to use webclient and I want to know the ouput

Getting ex.response yields nothing

```
        Dim adult = webClient.DownloadString("http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/apps/domainpark/domainpark.cgi?callback=_google_json_callback&output=js&client=ca-dp-godaddy2_xml&domain_name=" + CurrentBlog.Domain)
        'ias.NavigateTillComplete("https://api.bodis.com/domainclassification?domain=" + CurrentBlog.Domain)
        Dim result = ""
        Dim url = "http://api.bodis.com/domainclassification?domain=" + CurrentBlog.Domain
        Dim webRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Try
            response = DirectCast(webRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
            response = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse) 'is nothing there
        End Try

        Dim responseStream = response.GetResponseStream
```

Comment: Try [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx).

Comment: how to try that? how should I modify that code?>

Comment: Change Exception to WebException and see if new `ex` contains properties that help you identify the error in your case.

Comment: I don't need to know the error. I want to know the server response

Comment: Are you looking for [WebException.Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx)?

Comment: This is why I said - examine other properties and make a conclusion.